# How to send data from one ESP32 to another not using WiFi

Tags: c, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I'm currently trying to send a small data (like 10bytes) from one ESP32 board to another. The preferred architecture should be that many 'slave' nodes sends data to one 'master' node. All nodes are ESP32 microcontrollers and the max distance is ~3m.

I already have implemented this architecture using WiFi 'HTTP_GET' requests, but as I also need that each node scans for BLE beacons and gets the RSSI value.. the ESP32 flash memory was not enough...

The following error was thrown:

> Sketch uses 1661386 bytes (126%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.

That is the main reason why I want to avoid using WiFi library. Note: I tried to use sub-header files of `WiFi.h` but that was not enough.

### Question

Is there a lightweight implementation to simply send a small amount of data from one ESP32 to another using, for example, BLE signals ? If yes, would be nice to see the code sample!

### Edit

I resolved the memory problem. As it turns out, by default the ESP32 is not configured to use the full flash storage capacity. By minimizing the SPIFFS partition helped, now the sketch uses 84% memory storage! But the question still remains.

Comment: Are you  compiling in release mode optimized for size? Might also try a different device configuration. It seems the BLE library is very large. https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/1075

Comment: The optimization does nothing. :( Also, the device flash memory size is 4x less than mentioned in specification. Soo bad..

Comment: Ok, I think I found one solution.. Looks like it is possible to increase the flash memory 2x by reducing the SPIFFS partition size, it's called "Minimal SPIFFS".. For some reason my Arduino studio does not have this option in the tools menu, will try to change in the configuration!

Comment: I think you may want to look at BT mesh. It's pretty new, so take it with a grain of salt https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=10326